# How to center text in InputBase from material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

i am trying to center the text area of an InputBase element from material-ui.
Currently i am unsure if this is a bug or not.
An example how i tried to center the text area can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/hello-world-3yxcc).

My code looks like this:

```
import {
  InputBase,
  makeStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";

export default function EditTitle() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    input: {
      height: theme.typography.h1.fontSize,
      fontSize: theme.typography.h1.fontSize,
      fontWeight: theme.typography.h1.fontWeight,
      textAlign: "center",
      align: "center"
    }
  }));

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <InputBase
      inputProps={{ "aria-label": "naked" }}
      className={classes.input}
      defaultValue="Title"
      fullWidth={true}
      textAlign="center"
      align="center"
    ></InputBase>
  );
}
```

However the `text-align: center` is not set on the compiled website.
Current dependency list:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.4.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.4.3",
"next": "^9.0.6",
"react": "^16.9.0",
"react-dom": "^16.9.0",
"typeface-roboto": "0.0.75"
```

Any idea if i do something wrong or if this is indeed a bug?

Answer (score 2):

you can use align, textAlign to center the input, here is the component

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  inputStyle: {
    '&::-webkit-outer-spin-button, &::-webkit-inner-spin-button': {
      '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
      margin: '0',
    },
    align: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    '& input': {
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
    width: '60px',
  },
}))

const CustomTextFieldNumber = ({ number }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <TextField
      InputProps={{
        disableUnderline: true,
        classes: { input: classes.inputStyle },
      }}
      size="small"
      type="number"
      value={number}
    />
  )
}
```

or as well you can use inputProps={{ style: {textAlign: 'center'} }}
for example:

```
<TextField
          InputProps={{
            disableUnderline: true,
            classes: { input: classes.inputStyle },
          }}
          inputProps={{ style: {textAlign: 'center'} }}
          size="small"
          type="number"
          value={number}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to enable nested styling and define useStyle as following.

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    input: {
      height: theme.typography.h1.fontSize,
      fontSize: theme.typography.h1.fontSize,
      fontWeight: theme.typography.h1.fontWeight,
      textAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
      '& input': {
        textAlign: "center"
      }
    }
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue

```
const theme = createTheme({
  ...
  overrides: {
    MuiInputBase: {
      input: {
        textAlign: 'center'
      }
    }
  }
})
```